# error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@rails%2fujs: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.yarnpkg.com"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to rails and came across this error while creating my first rails app using rails new file_name.
Could anyone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because you've not installed yarn, as rails uses webpacker which requires it. You need to manually install this in the terminal. https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable